# to split the string in the column into multiple columns using oracle procedure

Tags: oracle

I am looking to split the string (comma separated) in column into multiple columns by using oracle procedure.

I am looking for the dynamic query as the number of columns need to be split will be unknown.

Comment: Splitting into columns, not rows? What will happen to the results - are you doing something with them in PL/SQL, or intending to pass the results back to a caller - if the latter how will they know how many columns to expect?

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done with static SQL, unless you want to make assumptions about the maximum number of columns.

If you can make some assumptions about the maximum number of columns, you can just return the values in, say, 100 output variables named `x_part1`, `x_part2`, ... `x_part100`.  Ugly but a lot easier.  You could also return `x_count` to tell the caller how many there were.

Otherwise, it can only be done using dynamic SQL (e.g., `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`) and then return a SYS_REFCURSOR to your caller.

But then, they'll have to use DBMS_SQL to convert the SYS_REFCURSOR to a DBMS_SQL cursor and then use that package to figure out how many columns are, what they are named, and then, ultimately, to fetch all the data.  A real pain.

#### DYNAMIC SQL EXAMPLE (as requested)

```
DECLARE
  i               NUMBER := 0;
  l_column_list   VARCHAR2 (32000) := NULL;
  l_sql           VARCHAR2 (32000);
  l_rc            SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (WITH test_data AS (SELECT 'a,b,ccc,ddddd,ee,,ggggg' test_string FROM DUAL),
                 parse1 AS
                   (SELECT test_string,
                           INSTR (',' || test_string || ',',
                                  ',',
                                  1,
                                  LEVEL)
                             start_pos,
                             INSTR (',' || test_string || ',',
                                    ',',
                                    1,
                                    LEVEL + 1)
                           - 2
                             end_pos
                    FROM   test_data
                    CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= LENGTH (REGEXP_REPLACE (test_string, '[^,]', '')) + 1)
            SELECT SUBSTR (test_string, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos + 1) field_part
            FROM   parse1) LOOP
    i := i + 1;

    IF l_column_list IS NOT NULL THEN
      l_column_list   := l_column_list || ',';
    END IF;

    l_column_list   := l_column_list || '''' || r.field_part || ''' as PART_' || LPAD (TO_CHAR (i), 3, '0');
  END LOOP;

  l_sql   := 'SELECT ' || l_column_list || ' FROM DUAL';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_sql);
  OPEN l_rc FOR l_sql;

  -- Return l_rc to the caller
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can i have some sample to create the dynamic SQL.

Comment: Hi, It is working fine, but the output is coming as select statement, which i want to insert into another table. can you tell me is there anyway to do that?

Comment: I mean to fetch the columns from the output of this procedure and to insert into another table by mapping the exact columns

Comment: That's where is gets really hard.  You need to use DBMS_SQL extensively for that.  If you can put a hard-limit on the number of possible columns, then you could `CREATE TYPE mytype AS OBJECT...` and then change the SELECT to `SELECT mytype(' || l_column_list || ') FROM DUAL`.  That way, you know you're only getting one column in the select, can fetch it, and then can insert the `mytype` fields into your table.

Comment: Is there any other way that we can add the insert statement in the for loop of above code itself, if both the tables are of same structure.

Comment: is it possible to send me the new code with adding the CREATE TYPE and the DMBS_SQL that you are talking about

Comment: I'm not your offshore development team.  But you misunderstood me: `CREATE TYPE` and `DBMS_SQL` are two different ways to go.  The former is much, much easier but requires that you hardcode a maximum number of potential columns (which you must be anyway, if you are inserting the results into a table).

Comment: I am sorry Matthew, i am just asking you to send me the sample code if you have any in such format, so that i can edit the same to match my requirement. I am really sorry if i trouble you.

Comment: No worries; I overreacted.  I recommend you try to create a type with, say, 100 columns and SELECT the parsed data as a single value of that type.  If you can't get it to work, post another question with the specific problem you're having at that point.

Comment: Hi mathew, i tried to modify the code and at the same time, inserted the records into another table also.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it.  It sort of makes the procedure less generic, since it now has knowledge of the caller's needs.  But whatever works.

Comment: Is there any chance that we can execute this procedure using .ctl file in unix?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
DECLARE
v_grades NUMBER;
v_sql1  VARCHAR2(32767);
v_sql2  VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN

-- SELECT COUNT (grade) INTO v_grades FROM example3 group by name;
SELECT MAX(grade_ct) INTO v_grades FROM
(SELECT COUNT (grade) as grade_ct, name FROM example3 group by name);
v_sql1 := 'INSERT INTO example2(name';
v_sql2 := 'SELECT name';
FOR i IN 1..v_grades LOOP
v_sql1 := v_sql1 || ',grade' || i;
v_sql2 := v_sql2 || ',MAX(DECODE(dr,' || i || ',grade))';
END LOOP;
v_sql1 := v_sql1 || ') ';
v_sql2 := v_sql1 || v_sql2
|| ' FROM (SELECT name,grade,ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY grade) dr FROM example3) GROUP BY name';
-- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_sql2);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql2;
END;
/

finally, i modified the code accordingly and is working.
```