# How to execute the Oralce Procedure from unix .ctl file

Tags: unix, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there any way to execute the oracle procedure from unix .ctl file.

I tried to call the procedure from .sh file and is success.

But i need to call the procedure from .ctl file.

Comment: Do you mean from SQL\*Loader? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: i have one stored procedure in oracle and i want to execute that procedure from unix using .ctl file.

Comment: is there anyway that we can write .ctl file in unix to call the stored procedure.

Comment: What do you mean by a .ctl file? If you aren't talking about a SQL\*Loader control file, what *do* you mean? What will execute or use your file?

Comment: i am sorry alex, i am talking about sql*loader control file only

Comment: Is this related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37445600/266304)? SQL\*Loader loads CSV data into a table, so I'm not clear how a procedure to split a string up would fit in. But your own answer to that question seems to be doing something completely different anyway. Take a step back and edit the question to explain what you are actually doing - including what data you're trying to load, with examples; what table structure you're putting it into; and then - if it's relevant - how your procedure fits in.

Comment: No, as i said earlier, i have one stored procedure in oracle.

Comment: And i want to execute that procedure using sql*loader control file

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make sense though. SQL\*Loader loads data from a text file into a table. What data? What table? How does it relate to the procedure? Why do you need to call it from SQL\*Loader? Without understanding what you're trying to do we can't say if it's possible.

Comment: I know that SQL*Loader loads data from a source file into a table. I am asking about is there any way that SQL*Loader can call the batch file (.sh) or the sql file (.sql) which inturn can call the oracle procedure.

Comment: i am really sorry alex if i confuse more on this.

Comment: Instead of loading data? After loading data? Calling for each inserted row? to change the data actually being inserted? One of those is possible, maybe. Again, edit the question and explain clearly what you need to do.

Comment: Thank you Alex.  I have one oracle procedure which is reading the data from XML source file and loading the data into temporary table, after that there is some exercise to transpose the data from temporary table as per the requirement and to load into the final table. Now i want to execute this procedure from unix sqlloader control file because, we have similar functionality in our environment using sqlloader control file to load the data from text file. we need adopt the same control file to execute the xml file with some special rerquirements (which is implemented in oracle procedure).

Comment: Have you resolved this now?

Comment: Not yet Alex, i could not find the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute a procedure through SQL*Loader, no. You can do transformations of individual field values but that isn't what you need here.

The simplest solution is probably to have a shell script which calls SQL*Loader and then calls SQL*Plus to execute the procedure. As a very rough outline:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sqlldr username/password control=/path/test_loading.ctl
sqlplus username/password <<!EOF
begin
  your_procedure(...);
end;
/
!EOF
```

So essentially the script you already have working to call your procedure, but with your call to SQL*Loader added to it.

That lets your control file match your 'similar functionality', and it just has a shell script wrapper around it.

Comment: Thank you Alex, but that is not the requirement.

Comment: I am looking to resolve that issue in another way probably. Thanks a lot for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Do this at command line sqlldr userid=someuser@somepassword control=some_loader_script.ctl